# Difference between stipulation and postulation

Tags: meaning, word-usage, confusables

What's the difference between stipulation and postulation?

I am a German native speaker and both words can be translated to the German 'Forderung'.

In what context can 'postulation' be used? Is it an antiquated word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Websters, *[stipulate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stipulate)* means to make an agreement or to demand an express term in an agreement. There's the sense that two or more minds are at work to agree on a specific term or set of terms.

*[Postulate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/postulate)*, says Wesbters, is "to assume or claim as true, existent, or necessary." There's no sense of two minds coming to agreement and memorializing it.

*Postulate* isn't antiquated, but usually used in the context of setting or assuming terms in an argument or proposition.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and the links. That helped a lot.